# Thoughts on a history-of-ubuntu tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Other sites I frequent have a tag related to history (not your command history):

- [Unix & Linux: history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/history)
- [Vi and Vim: history-of](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tags/history-of)
- [Science Fiction and Fantasy: history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of)

And others:

- [English Language & Usage: history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)
- [Photography: history](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)
- [TeX and LaTeX: tex-history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-history)
- [Information Security: history](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and [Super User: history](https://superuser.com/tags/history/) are examples of ill-defined scope.
- It's [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/are-questions-about-programming-history-in-scope-for-stack-overflow), but on topic on [Programmers: history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/history/)

For some time now, I have felt we could use a similar tag. Questions like the following:

- [Why did the Ubuntu GNOME logo change in 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711474/why-did-the-ubuntu-gnome-logo-change-in-15-10)
- [What's the meaning of the Ubuntu logo? Where does it come from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42724/whats-the-meaning-of-the-ubuntu-logo-where-does-it-come-from)
- [Why is Canonical choosing QT over GTK for Unity's next generation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/281092/158442)
- [Why did Ubuntu stop free shipping of its CDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131139/why-did-ubuntu-stop-free-shipping-of-its-cds)
- [What's the reason for Ubuntu officially supporting versions such as Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694277/whats-the-reason-for-ubuntu-officially-supporting-versions-such-as-kubuntu-lub)
- [What happened to Ubuntu Certified Professional?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326428/what-happened-to-ubuntu-certified-professional) (closed as a dupe of [What is the current state of the Ubuntu Professional certification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87445/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-ubuntu-professional-certification))
- [What happened to Android Execution Environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20251/what-happened-to-android-execution-environment) (closed as a dupe of [Plans to make Android Apps run on Ubuntu abandoned?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17316/plans-to-make-android-apps-run-on-ubuntu-abandoned))
- [What happened to the Leadership Code of Conduct?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250991/what-happened-to-the-leadership-code-of-conduct)
- [What happened to Ubuntu's Hall of Fame page?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502280/what-happened-to-ubuntus-hall-of-fame-page)
- [What happened to Gobuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56547/what-happened-to-gobuntu)
- [Why is bash the default shell in most OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638918/why-is-bash-the-default-shell-in-most-os)
- [How new is ctrl+r?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704096/how-new-is-ctrlr)

These questions ask why some things happened the way they did, which is what history is. Thoughts?

Comment: +1 I think this is be a great idea! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While it smells an awful lot like a meta tag, I can certainly see the value:

- It tells potential answerers what the user is looking for (a historical report).
- It should be interesting for people to read through.

But like [software-recommendations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations), it shouldn't be used alone; there should be other tags.

Anyway I'm looking forward to seeing what other people think. Let this tick over for a week and let's go with the vote (unless somebody points out a serious issue).

Comment: I agree. I would definitely favourite this tag. Maybe even subscribe.

Comment: At +17/-1, I have created the tag, and added it to 10 questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all about this tag.  Short post